# Put in vs Put into vs Put inside

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

Is there a serious difference between the following three sentences:

> - I put the toys **in** the box.
> - I put the toys **into** the box.
> - I put the toys **inside** the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *significant* difference between them - in **this** context. 
It is a matter of choice and personal style. Nevertheless, people prefer the shorter way as usual: "he is putting the toys **in** the box".

In other contexts may be differences between them. Be aware that normally the word "into" is a preposition for movement or transformation while inside is preposition for location. Also see [that](https://www.espressoenglish.net/english-prepositions-in-inside-into-within/) and [this](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst64784_in---into---inside.aspx).